# is it possible a simultaneous run of main thread and its child thread in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, systems-programming

I have to read some file (logs) from a server using thread program in c. The program should remain simultaneous means on one hand this child thread should be executing and on same time main thread should be informing time of its child tread.

So in sample program I am trying to run a logging function in child thread and on same time parent process/parent thread/main thread will be printing time in seconds have been passed running the logging.

PS: my problem is if I will use pthread_join() then first logreading function will execute which is actually blocking thread due to infinite loop. And I am not able to get take flow of control in main function. Anyhow I want to execute both together without interrupting each other . I have done similar thing in Java using thread and synchronized methods. But in C I have not that much knowledge of multithreading programming

Currently I am not using locks because I don't want stop/resume condition, my only requirement is that both functions keep started , running at the same time without interacting each other.
Thanks for the help.

```
void process(FILE *FP, int sockfd);
int create_ma_header(char*, int, int, int, int);
void* t_main(void*);

int i;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  void* arg;
  void* t_result;
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("usage: tcpcli <IPaddress>");
    exit(0);
  }
  arg = (void*) argv[1];
  pthread_t t;
  pthread_attr_t t_attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&t_attr);
  printf("before calling pthread_create getpid: %d getpthread_self %u tid:%u\n",
      getpid(), pthread_self(), syscall(SYS_gettid));
  pthread_create(&t, &t_attr, t_main, (void*) argv[1]); //loging tread
  /* if(pthread_join(t,&t_result) != 0)
   {
   printf("Thread not joined \n");
   exit(1);
   }
   */
  printf("Thread joined and status is  Logs are getting printed what else you want to do .... \n");
  while (1)
  {
    printf(
        "Running time of log reading displayed from main thread: %d    seconds",
        i++);
    slep(1);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void* loging_thread(void* arg)
{
  char* server_ip;
  server_ip = (char*) arg;
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, server_ip, &servaddr.sin_addr);

  printf(
      "in loging_thread log has been redirected to log_read.dat getpid: %d getpthread_self %u tid:%u\n",
      getpid(), pthread_self(), syscall(SYS_gettid));
  connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  process(stdin, sockfd); /* do it all */
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void process(FILE *fp, int sockfd)
{
  FILE* log_f;
  int fd;
  fd = open("log_read.dat", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
  char sendline[MAXLINE];
  char reply[MAXLINE], string2[MAXLINE], *body;
  char *p1, *p2, *p3;
  create_ma_header(reply, 999, 999, VERSION, 999);
  write(sockfd, reply, sizeof(reply));
  while (1)
  {
    char header[SDNS_MA_HEADERSZ];
    read(sockfd, body, size);
    write(fd, body, size);
  }
}

int create_ma_header(char * reply, int type, int size, int version, int lic)
{
  sprintf(reply, "%4d%c%10d%c%4d%c%4d", type, SD_PIPE, size, SD_PIPE, version,
      SD_PIPE, lic);
  if (strlen(reply) != 26 - 1)
  {

    return 0;
  }
  reply[strlen(reply)] = SD_PIPE;
  return 1;
}

char * get_ma_header(char *curr_p, int *type_p, int *size_p, int *version_p,
    int *lic_p)
{
  *type_p = (int) strtol(curr_p, NULL, 10);
  curr_p += 5;
  *size_p = (int) strtol(curr_p, NULL, 10);
  curr_p += 11;
  *version_p = (int) strtol(curr_p, NULL, 10);
  curr_p += 5;
  *lic_p = (int) strtol(curr_p, NULL, 10);
  curr_p += 5;
  return curr_p;
}
```

Comment: pthread_join() will block until thread is ended. Use it AFTER your while loop in main (when you want to stop program).

Comment: Please take several hours or days to read some good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). We can't teach you all that in a few minutes and a few paragraphs. And you very probably *have to synchronize* (with mutexes or other ways). Don't forget to `fflush` and/or end your `printf` format strings with `\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to misunderstand what `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` do.

After `pthread_create` you will have two threads running in parallel. You need do nothing more to have them both do whatever they do. Neither thread "has control", they just both exist.

When a thread, "B", has completed whatever it needed to do, it can "return" a value. Thread "B" then ceases to run (to *do* anything), but the return value is stored away until it it needed.

Another thread, "A", can retrieve the return value from a completed thread by running `pthread_join`. If thread "B" is, in fact, not yet completed (it is still running), then the `pthread_join` will block thread "A" until thread "B" is complete and a value has been returned.

Thus, calling `pthread_join` on a thread "B" that never exits is a mistake.

There are two reason to use `pthread_join`:

1. To obtain the return value.
2. To make sure that the program does not exit before all the threads have finished.

So, in your program you don't really want a `pthread_join` at all.